# Haskell: Counter-intuitive type checking going on

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers, typechecking

So I have these type:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT {runStateT :: s -> m (a, s)}

data MTa a = FailTa Exception
        | DoneTa {unpackDoneTa :: (a, O)}
        deriving Show

type O = String
type Exception = String
type State = Int
```

I made `(State s m)` an instance of the `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad` classes like so:

```
instance (Monad m) => Functor (StateT s m) where
    fmap f t = StateT $ \is -> do
                    ~(a, s) <- runStateT t is
                    return (f a, s)

instance (Monad m) => Applicative (StateT s m) where
    pure = return
    StateT f <*> StateT t = StateT $ \is -> do
        ~(ta, ts) <- t is
        ~(fa, fs) <- f ts
        return (fa ta, fs)

instance (Monad m) => Monad (StateT s m) where
    return a = StateT $ \s -> return (a, s)
    StateT m1 >>= k = StateT $ \s -> do
        ~(a, s1) <- m1 s
        let StateT m2 = k a
        m2 s1
```

I also made `MTa` an instance of the `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad` classes:

```
instance Functor MTa where
    _ `fmap` (FailTa e) = FailTa e
    f `fmap` (DoneTa (a, o)) = DoneTa (f a, o)

instance Applicative MTa where
    pure = return
    _ <*> (FailTa e) = FailTa e
    FailTa e <*> _ = FailTa e
    DoneTa (f, x) <*> DoneTa (a, y) = DoneTa (f a, y ++ x)

instance Monad MTa where
    return a = DoneTa (a, "")
    m >>= f = case m of
        FailTa e -> FailTa e
        DoneTa (a, x) -> case (f a) of
            FailTa e1 -> FailTa e1
            DoneTa (b, y) -> DoneTa (b, x ++ y)
```

I then have this function:

```
incTaState :: StateT State MTa ()
incTaState = StateT $ \s -> return ((), s+1)
```

Am I right to think that `return ((), s+1)` will evaluate to `DoneTa (((), s+1), "")`. If so, doesn't that mean that its type is `MTa ((), State)`. Why does `incTaState` typecheck to `StateT State MTa ()`? When I run this: `:t DoneTa ((), "")` in a console, it evaluates to `DoneTa ((), "") :: MTa ()`. Am I not interpreting the return part of `incTaState` correctly?

The question can almost be summarized like so: if `Done ((), "")` typechecks to `MTa ()`, how is it that `incTaState` typechecks to `StateT State MTa ()`? Doesn't `DoneTa (((), s+1), "")`, the resolution of `return ((), s+1)`, typecheck to `MTa (((), State), O)` making `incTaState` a type of `StateT State MTa ((), State)` not what is specified?

Please fell free to be verbose (-vvv).

Your consideration is much appreciated. Peace.

**Below is removed as I made a mistake by entering a 3-tuple. Thanks @HTNW.**

I suspect I'm not because when I run `:t (StateT $ \s -> DoneTa (((), s+1, "")))` I get the following error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘((a, b), O)’
                  with actual type ‘((), b, [Char])’
• In the first argument of ‘DoneTa’, namely ‘(((), s + 1, ""))’
  In the expression: DoneTa (((), s + 1, ""))
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘\ s -> DoneTa (((), s + 1, ""))’
• Relevant bindings include s :: b (bound at <interactive>:1:12)
```

Comment: I see why I was confused now. I kept on looking at the declaration of the `StateT s m a` type as wanting a monad that takes two arguments (whatever that means) instead of a type that wants a monad containing a 2-tuple which `DoneTa (((), s+1), "")` is. When `incTaState` is evaluated to `StateT $ \s -> DoneTa (((), s+1), "")`, we see that as per the  `StateT s m a` declaration, `a` is `((), s+1)`. Looking at this 2-tuple and the `MTa a` type declaration, `a` is `()` making the return type of `incTaState` `StateT State MTa ()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
incTaState :: StateT State MTa ()
incTaState = StateT $ \s -> return ((), s+1)
\s -> ((), s+1)          :: State -> ((), State)
-- You were correct
\s -> return ((), s + 1) :: State -> MTa ((), State)
-- The type of that function matches up with StateT
-- We can set s = State, m = MTa, and a = ()
StateT s     m   a  = s     -> m   (a , s    )
StateT State MTa () = State -> MTa ((), State)
-- So:
StateT $ \s -> return ((), s+1) :: StateT State MTa ()
-- QED
```

When you run `StateT $ \s -> DoneTa ((), s+1, "")`, the issue is that `DoneTa :: (a, String) -> MTa a`, with a 2-tuple, but you are passing it `((), s + 1, "") :: ((), State, String)`, a 3-tuple. Add more nesting: `StateT $ \s -> DoneTa (((), s + 1), "")` (where `(((), s + 1), "") :: (((), State), String)`, a 2-tuple with a 2-tuple inside it).

Comment: Ah. Thank you. That was a mistake. Edited the question.

Comment: Edited the question.